# De una lista de tuplas obtener el maximo immprimendo tanto clave como valor

Tags: python, csv

Tengo esta lista y quiero obtener el máximo con clave y valor, pero dependiendo del valor, ¿cómo se hace?

```
Contador ({'B': 7, 'C': 6, 'K': 5, 'S': 5, 'M': 4, 'D': 3, 'J': 3, 'O': 3 , 'F': 2, 'H': 2, 'L': 2, 'A': 1, 'E': 1, 'G': 1, 'N': 1, 'P': 1, ' R ': 1,' T ': 1})
```

Gracias

Comment: El ejemplo que das no es una lista de tuplas, me arriesgaría a decir que es un objeto de la clase `<class 'collections.Counter'>`, si este fuera el caso la forma de obtener el valor máximo como dices es usando `most_common()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]    import operator

```
stats = ({'B': 7, 'C': 6, 'K': 5, 'S': 5, 'M': 4, 'D': 3, 'J': 3, 'O': 3 , 'F': 2, 'H': 2, 'L': 2, 'A': 1, 'E': 1, 'G': 1, 'N': 1, 'P': 1, ' R ': 1,' T ': 1})
max_key = max(stats.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print(max_key,stats.get(max_key))
```

lo puedes probar aca

https://paiza.io/projects/pqvYuKhMjYdyJnrID7LAwQ

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: con todo gusto estimado estamos para colaborar

Comment: lo que me faltaba, una respuesta con código en imagen. Las imágenes mostrando código no son bien recibidas, por suerte también lo has colocado como texto y se agradece. Por favor lee [answer]